# Record Set won't open - connecting to Oracle Database

Tags: vba, oracle, excel, ado, recordset

Below is a modified code of what I'm trying to run. I basically pass a SQL query file as text to run the query from vba and have the results automatically return in a worksheet.

This was working for me when I was connecting to SQL Server, but it seems the recordset is closed when I'm using an Oracle server, so I'm guessing my connection string is the issue. But I really don't know where exactly my issue is since the info in my connection string matches the *TNSNAMES*, and I know my username and pw is in working order as I can log in and run queries via PL/SQL.

Also, my query runs fine when I run in in PL/SQL, and no, it doesn't return a `NULL` set. I've also tried it with a really simplified `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <= 2` query and it still doesn't work.

Edit1: However,`Select 1 FROM dual` works.

Edit2: So after I ran the `Select 1 FROM dual` query, the really simple query worked. However, the original query still doesn't work.

```vb
Sub Con_DatabaseName(EvalDate As String, fPath1 As String, fName1 As String, fPath2 As String, fName2 As String)

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

con.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
"(HOST=xxxx)" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx))); uid=xxxx; pwd=xxxx;"

con.CommandTimeout = 0
con.Open

Dim QueryFile As String
Dim SqlStatement As String
Dim hFile As Long

QueryFile = fPath2 & fName2
'Debug.Print QueryFile

hFile = FreeFile
Open QueryFile For Input As #hFile
SqlStatement = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
Close #hFile
Debug.Print SqlStatement

Dim col As Integer

rs.Open SqlStatement, con
'Checks if my recordset is open.
If rs.State = 1 Then
   MsgBox ("Recordset is open")
ElseIf rs.State <> 1 Then
  MsgBox ("Recordset is not open")
  Exit Sub
End If

rs.Close
con.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If you debug.print the SQL can you run it via a query tool?

Comment: @Tim Yes, my SQL statement is fine. It doesn't return a null set either.

Comment: I'd expect an error if your SQL somehow failed - do you have any error handling inp lace, or is this your exact code?  Can you run a simple SQL like "select 1 from dual" for example?

Comment: @Tim So "select 1 From dual" works... but "Select * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <=10" doesn't... I'm not sure what that means as I can run the latter perfectly fine in PLSQL

Comment: Are you using the same credentials in both cases?  Are you really seeing no errors at all?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same credentials. When I run the code above with my original SQL code, it runs straight into the Recordset is not Open section. No errors pop up concerning my SQL code.

Also, the "Select * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <=10" now works...

Comment: @TimWilliams So I realized the simple query worked because I directly wrote it into the code - however, when I saved that as a SQL query file and called it from there, that's when it stops working. The weird thing though is that I can see what queries are actually being passed through using the debug.print, and it is passing through the exact same string whether I've directly coded it or saving as a .sql file...

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for all your help. The error came b/c I had comments in the beginning of my code like 
"--This query is for yadda yadda yadda"
which caused the recordset issue in Excel but no in PLSQL

Comment: Use in line commenting `/* comment */` instead of `--` some parsers I've seen miss the double dash syntax.